# XML Rendering in DIV

Tags: html, xml, django, formatting

While working on a crash statistics website I came across the following situation.

I have a Django installation running as our crash statistics website, it servers dynamic webpages and I need it to display (among other info) one of the crash logs uploaded by users of our application. These logs are in XML and roughly formed as follows:

```
<?xml ... ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ... ?>
...
<RunTimeLog>
   <xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet"/>
   <xsl:template match="/RunTimeLog">
      <html>
         <head>
            <style type="text/css">
               ... some styling code ...
            </style>
            <script language="javascript">
               ... some dynamics code ...
            </script>
         </head>
         <body>
            ... some HTML, XSL and JS for the page layout ...
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   <LogHeader>
      ...
   </LogHeader>
   <LogEvents>
      ...
   </LogEvents>
</RunTimeLog>
```

Now, as you can see this includes everything needed to render a log file in one file (because we want the logs to be easily distributable AND readable). This code works as a charm, when opening the XML in the browser a nicely formatted log appears. Now I'm trying to render this in a different page using the following Django template:

```
<html>
   <head>
      ... import JQuery and other awesome stuff ...
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="log">
      </div>
      <div id="logbuffer">
         {{ log }} <!-- Django inserts the raw XML in here... -->
      </div>
      <script>
         xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
         resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment($('#logbuffer').innerHTML, document);
         $('log').append(resultDocument);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, this doesn't work... The logbuffer div does display the raw XML as expected, but formatting doesn't work and the second line in the script returns *null* to *resultDocument*.

I'm wondering wether this is the right approach? Does anyone know why this isn't working? I know there are different ways of solving this problem on the Django side, but I'd rather keep the formatting client side.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ log }}` inserts the **escaped** html, not the raw.  So `$('#logbuffer').innerHTML` returns the

```
&lt;?xml ... ?&gt;
&lt;?xml-stylesheet type=&quot;text/xsl&quot; ... ?&gt;
and so on...
```

You have to mark the `log` variable as safe:

```
{{ log|safe }}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it :). Even more simple than I had expected :P.